# Regular differentiable curve has strong tangent

Tags: curves, tangent-line

I have a doubt about exercise 1.3.7 from the book *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* by Do Carmo.

The exercise asks to prove that a curve $\alpha$ which is $C^1$ at $t_0$ and $\alpha'(t_0)\neq 0$ has a **strong tangent** at $t_0$. The definition of strong tangent can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036038/weak-tangent-but-not-a-strong-tangent).

**My attempt:** The line that goes trough $\alpha(t_0+h)$ and $\alpha(t_0+k)$ is
$$\{ \lambda(\alpha(t_0+h)-\alpha(t_0+k))+\alpha(t_0+h):\lambda\in \mathbb{R} \}.$$

I don't understand how the limit $h,k\to 0$ should be taken in the above expression. As $h,k\to 0$, the line should become
$$\{ \lambda \alpha'(t_0)+\alpha(t_0):\lambda\in \mathbb{R} \}.$$

Do Carmo gives the following hint to solve this exercise
$$\frac{\alpha(t_0+h)-\alpha(t_0+k)}{h-k}\xrightarrow{h,k\to0}\alpha'(t_0).$$
I understand why this is true (Mean Value Theorem) but I don't know what this tells us about the line.

Thanks!

Comment: check out [cusps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity))

Comment: Your "line through $\alpha(t_0+h)$ and $\alpha(t_0+k)$" does not go through $\alpha(t_0+k)$. As for your comments, do you not see anything in common between that difference quotient and your (slightly mistaken) parametric formula for the line?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, my line indeed goes trough $\alpha(t_0+k)$ (take $\lambda=-1$). Of course I see something in common betwwen them but I don't know how to formalize the proof.

Comment: My apology - you are correct. For the next step, note that in your expression for the line, $h, k$ are fixed values, while every value of $\lambda$ makes an appearance in the set. So if you were to change the value of $\lambda$ by some factor, it would just be another point in the same set. After that, you can consider how the set changes when $h, k$ get smaller.